# Can I use the Split Ray metamagic feat on the Ray of Exhaustion spell like this?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats, metamagic, targeting

Does this sequence work?

1. I use the Split Ray metamagic on the Ray of Exhaustion spell
2. With the first ray, I hit enemy A
3. If he does not fail the Fort save, I hit him with the second ray; now he is exhausted, no save
4. If he fails, I hit enemy B with the second ray

Basically, am I allowed to define the second target *after* I have seen the result on the first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Split Ray doesn't have a wait-and-see option

The final part of the benefit of feat **Split Ray** says that "all rays must be aimed at targets within 30 feet of each other *and fired simultaneously*" (*Complete Arcane* 83 and emphasis mine).

Thus a caster that casts a ray spell modified by the feat Split Ray picks the targets of his rays then launches all the rays at once.

While the caster *can* pick to aim both rays at one target then launch both rays at that lone target, the caster *can't* aim one ray at a target, launch that ray, examine the target to determine if the ray affected that target, then aim the second ray and launch it at the same or a different target. Although that *would* be awesome, sadly the pair of rays are launched as a group.

Comment: I need to learn to read every word